# Decryption method for two keys

Tags: java

I am working on a decryption method for two keys for my CaesarCipher class. I have the decryption method for one key but I am lost on what I need to do when two keys are used. How can I fix my decryption method for two keys? The four represent the letter "e" which makes everything relative to the letter "e". The 26 represents the amount of letters in the alphabet.
Below is the decryption method I used for one key:

```
public String decrypt(String encrypted){
    CaesarCipher23 cc = new CaesarCipher23();
    int[] freqs = countLetters(encrypted);
    int maxDex=indexOfMax(freqs);
    int dkey=maxDex-4;

    if(maxDex<4){
        dkey=26-(4-maxDex);
    }

    return cc.encrypt(encrypted,26-dkey);

}
```

This is what I've started for my two key decryption method:

```
public String decryptTwoKeys(String encrypted){
     String firstHalf=halfOfString(encrypted,0);
     String secondHalf=halfOfString(encrypted,1);
     int key1=getKey(firstHalf);
     int key2= getKey(secondHalf);
     System.out.println("this is key1"+"\t"+ key1+"this is key2"+"\t"+key2); 
     CaesarCipher23 cc = new CaesarCipher23();
     return cc.encrptyTwoKeys(encrypted,key1,key2);
    }
```

I am looking forward to feedback on how I can improve my code. I am a beginner at Java and I am trying to find a better way at solving this problem. Advice would be great.

Comment: Why am I being downvoted for simply asking a question that pertains to work that I am doing. This is absurd.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, but there are problems with it. In particular: [1] The code provided is incomplete. For example, where are methods _halfOfString()_, _getKey()_, _encrypt()_ and _encryptTwoKeys()_? [2] You have not clearly expressed the specific problem you need help with. Try modifying your question to address those issues.

Comment: @skomisa I'm really confused on what to do because if I have too much code in the problem I get downvoted if I have too little I get downvoted. The issue was in my getKey method and I'll change the question to reflect that.I appreciate the feedback and will implement it later today

Comment: If you have too much code to post then you need to create a simplified version (_"MCVE"_) of your code that others can copy and run. For an issue involving encryption and decryption there shouldn't be a lot of code. See [_How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to do was fix my getKey method. The changes below are what I did:

```
public int getKey(String s){
 int [] arr=countLetters(s);
 int maxDex=indexOfMax(arr);
 int key;
 if (maxDex<4) key= maxDex-4+26;
 else key=maxDex-4;
 return key;
 }
```